# Powershell -like syntax with hyphens

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, sql-like

This is probably a newb question, but I've spent a couple hours on this now.
I am creating a powershell script, trying to determine if an entry already exists.
(This is for an Exchange multi-tenant solution)
This works:

> ```
> Get-GlobalAddressList | Where{$_.Identity -Like "\MyCompany_com*"}
> ```

But this fails:

> ```
> Get-GlobalAddressList | Where{$_.Identity -Like "\MyCompany_com - GAL"}
> ```

For some reason I can't fathom, the spaces in the entry won't match.

Yes, I am certain that the entry `\MyCompany_com - GAL` exists.
I have tried every combination I can think of using -match, -eq, -contains
Any help is appreciated!

---- Edit ----------------------

Tried a new tact, still failing miserably:

```
$NewVal = "\MyCompany_com - GAL"
$Prop = Get-GlobalAddressList | Select Name
foreach($PropVal in $Prop.Name){
  write-output "comparing: $NewVal to $PropVal"
  if($NewVal -like $PropVal){write-output "MATCH"} else {write-output "no-match"}
}
```

The write-output 'shows' a match character for character.

I have scripted in many languages for over 3 decades, but this PowerShell crap has me baffled.  #frustrated#

---- Edit #2 (showing output) ----------------------

```
comparing: MyCompany_com - GAL to MyCustomer_com - GAL
no-match
comparing: MyCompany_com - GAL to MyCompany_com - GAL
no-match
comparing: MyCompany_com - GAL to Default Global Address List
no-match
```

Any way to force a string comparison?

Are the space characters still messing me up?

---- Edit #3 (still trying) ----------------------

I created a new GlobalAddressList: `"MCC-GAL"` purposely with no spaces.

This still does not work:

> ```
> Get-GlobalAddressList | Where{$_.Name -Like "MCC-GAL"}
> ```

However, this DOES match:

> ```
> Get-GlobalAddressList | Where{$_.Name -Like "MCC?GAL"}
> ```

So in addition to the space characters, the hyphen (-) is also causing match problems.  I did try to escape the hyphen: "\-", but still no match.

Is there *ANY WAY* to force a *simple* string comparison?
The method I am using to build the compared string will be what I need to match with.

Comment: Output the character ordinals? You may have an embedded tab character that when displayed becomes a space or perhaps an en dash instead of a regular hyphen/dash character. Something like `foreach ($PropVal in $Prop.Name) { Write-Output [int]$PropVal }` ought to work hopefully. Compare that output with the output of the same code, substituting `$NewVal` in place of `$Prop.Name`. I'd use -match with a regex that allows any spacing character if -like fails, but I'm a PS newb as well, so maybe that is a naive solution. At the very least, it'll confirm whether spaces are the issue.

Comment: I wish I could get the [int] syntax to work, it would be nice to verify, but several attempts did not return the char-codes as hoped.  As it happens, I have in a text file the original command I copy/pasted to create that entry, and I copy/pasted that exact same text into my PS script.  So unless AD is doing some type of coversion this should be the exact same text.  Thanks for suggestion tho!!

Comment: `Where {[string]::Compare($_.Name, "MCC-GAL", $True)}` via [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx)? I wouldn't put much stock in it, however, seeing as how the "CompareTo" method is described as a case-insensitive comparison, yet the two sample strings do not compare equal despite being the same except for case. I hope that helps. It really shouldn't be this difficult........ -_-

Comment: Thanks again @Chrono for the suggestion, stil no-go.  Agreed: "this really shouldn't be this difficult"!!  I have tried numerous other syntax variations, including: [regex]::escape, curly-brackets, single-quotes, -eq, -match.  All I need to do is test to make sure the GlobalAddressBook object doesn't already exist in my script before creating a new one.  I have tried other tacts like trying the -Identity switch for Get-GlobalAddressList, but for some mysterious reason I just can't get a match.  Ugh, so much time wasted now.

Comment: well, that was lame, I couln't add the tag 'exchange-2013' because I have a crappy reputation - lol - #sigh#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I had a work-around for GetAddressList, the next part of my script I was forced to figure out this issue.

Determination:  I shared the same concern as @user2460798, but felt safe to disregard since I had copy/pasted to the power-shell line the GlobalAddressList name with the "normal" dash.  As it turns out, the sample commands we copied contained the en-dash.  Ouch, lesson learned.  Over 14 hours wasted on this for my co-worker and me. #crying#

I finally stumbled upon a script, [How to convert a ascii string into a decimal representative string in a powershell script?](http://myridia.com/dev_posts/view/822)
, that with some slight modification I was able to reveal that the value stored in AD was in fact an "en-dash", [char]8211 (a normal dash is [char]045).

So, here is the command that will match the entry I was trying to retrieve:

```
Get-GlobalAddressList | Where{$_.Name.replace([convert]::ToChar(8211),"-") -eq "MyCompany_com - GAL"}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you get if you enter just type in:

```
"\MyCompany_com - GAL" -like "\MyCompany_com - GAL"
```

If that works then it strongly suggests that the $_.Identity property has some characters in it that are different than what you think. Here is one way you can see exactly what characters a string contains:

```
[char[]]$stringWithOddCharacters   # breaks the string into characters
[byte[]][char[]]$stringWithOddCharacters   # converts each character into a byte
```

So you could do something like

```
Get-GlobalAddressList | foreach-object {
  if ($_.Identity -Like "\MyCompany_com*") {
    [char[]]($_.Identity.ToString())
    [byte[]][char[]]($_.Identity.ToString())
  }
}
```

to see exactly what's in the Identity property. Note that if Identity contains Unicode characters that don't convert to ASCII you'll need to change [byte[]] to [int16[]]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no closer. No hidden characters detected:
`\ M y C o m p a n y _ c o m - G A L`

Comment: So the $_.identity string has the exact same set of byte values as the string "\MyCompany_com - GAL"? (you can do the same thing with the constant string, as with $_.identity) They are each 20 long with these values: 92, 77, 121, 67, 111, 109, 112, 97, 110, 121, 95, 99, 111, 109, 32, 45, 32, 71, 65, 76?? What does this give you: `"\MyCompany_com - GAL" -Like "\MyCompany_com - GAL"`

Comment: sorry for not answering the 1st question, the simple -Like comparison returns true.  I couldn't get the byte syntax to work: `Unexpected token '[byte[]][char[]]$_.Identity' in expression or statement.`  Again, thanks for the suggestions!!  I'll try again the byte syntax.

Comment: Error returned:
`foreach-object : Cannot convert the "\MyCompany_com - GAL" value of type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId" to type "System.Char[]".`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Exchange .NET classes, so I didn't know that $_.Identity wasn't a string. (The error message says it is a Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId). In order to cast a string to a character array (using [char[]]) the "string" has to really be a string. To do that use: `$_.Identity.ToString()` instead of $_.Identity. I'll edit the answer to make it clearer (I also put in a pair of parenthesis that shouldn't be needed, but will make it a little clearer what's happening)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was able to match on a different object in the GlobalAddressList object:

```
Get-GlobalAddressList | Where{$_.ConditionalCustomAttribute1 -eq "MMC"}
```

With this being a multi-tenant solution, we have been adding a value to the `ConditionalCustomAttribute1` object, that (in our situation) will be unique and therefore suitable for testing the existence of.

This doesn't answer the original question, but it solves my scripting task.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this post while searching for the -Filter switch syntax. Your first script example was correct because the -like switch should be used with a wildcard character. Try replacing -Like with -Match (no wildcard) in your second script example.